# How did Christianity change the treatment of women in the Roman Empire?

Tags: women

Christianity gets a bad reputation in its treatment of women in the modern day. However, when contrasting with the Roman Empire was it an improvement?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)